# Using Hydrogen Peroxide to clean toilet

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I want to use lysol hydrogen peroxide multipurpose cleaner for cleaning my toilet. Is this a dangerous course of action?

Comment: yes i can see multiple link showing it can be use. you can check out [this](http://www.houselogic.com/home-advice/green-cleaning/uses-for-hydrogen-peroxide/) and [this](http://www.using-hydrogen-peroxide.com/using-hydrogen-peroxide-for-cleaning.html)

Answer (score 2):

Lysol Multipurpose Cleaner with hydrogen peroxide contains only 0.5% hydrogen peroxide. [This site](http://www.using-hydrogen-peroxide.com/using-hydrogen-peroxide-for-cleaning.html) (**using-hydrogen-peroxide.com**) suggests using up to 35% hydrogen peroxide for cleaning toilets. This hydrogen peroxide website (and who knew it had one) may be biased, but that's quite a margin between the product you want to use and what the website says is safe. I would feel pretty comfortable using this Lysol product for cleaning toilets (except that it may actually *not be strong enough*!).